# In Visual Studio 2019, how do I add my project assemblies (or any assemblies at all) to the C# interactive pane?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, c#-interactive

> This question [is not answered by the proposed duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135571). There is no "Initialize Interactive with Project" option when I right click my project.

I want to test out some code without creating another project and writing a console application. My project includes a reference to `System.Windows.Forms` and I can use the `Forms` namespace within my project, however, I cannot use it in C# interactive due to the following error:

```
> using System.Windows.Forms;
(1,22): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Forms' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

I've done a bit of sleuthing but I can't find too much information on this feature of Visual Studio. I thought to try loading the assembly with reflection but while loading the assembly did work, C# interactive still cannot find the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace:

```
> Assembly.LoadFile("@C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref\3.1.0\ref\netcoreapp3.1\System.Windows.Forms.dll")`
using System.Windows.Forms;
(1,14): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Windows' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Do note that I made sure to run `#reset core` to switch to .NET Core to match the version of the assembly I tried to load.

---

Whether it's using reflection to load the assembly or a more graceful method, how do I load a non-default assembly in a usable fashion within the C# Interactive pane of Visual Studio 2019?

Comment: See the following [blog entry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2016/january/essential-net-csharp-scripting)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can the C# interactive window interact with my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135571/can-the-c-sharp-interactive-window-interact-with-my-code)

Comment: @gunr2171 Unfortunately not. The option to "Reset C# interactive from project" does not exist when I right click either the solution or project as detailed in that thread.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest order the answers by Active, try the option from Mahmoud Hanafy

Comment: @HansPassant Even if I run `#reset core`? It's showing I'm running as .NET Core in the pane tab.

Comment: @hanspassant Either way that worked. If you post as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For C# Interactive, you can load a DLL directly using the `#r` directive.

simply execute the following:

```
> #r "C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref\3.1.0\ref\netcoreapp3.1\System.Windows.Forms.dll"
```

or more generic:

```
> #r "C:\YOUR\DLL\PATH"
```

Afterward, you should be able to access the namespace from the assembly.

You can also run your project with C# interactive. Just open the C# interactive window, then Right-Click the Project in your solution explorer, and select "*Initialize Interactive with Project*", which will also load all of your project assemblies in C# interactive.

[image]

Good luck!

Comment: I've marked this as the solution but note that the "Initialize Interactive with Project" option is not showing for me, so I've had to resort to the `#r` method.

Comment: I'm glad you at least could get it working! The "Initialize Interactive with Project" really just automatically pipes the `#r` command into the console, so you could likely make your own tool to do that as well.

Comment: Doing some research in a blog post from another comment there is a way to script this I guess. But it's a pain that the menu option isn't working for me on a .NET Core project in VS 2019. [I counter your screenshot with a screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/sneQduD). But either way, the `#r` directive is working for me.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57861538/1043380) explains why the "Initialize Interactive with Project" option doesn't exist.